# jQuery Promise for asynchronous loops

Tags: jquery, loops, sharepoint, asynchronous

I need to wait for an asynchronous call, then go to the next "i" and continue the loop.
My code:

```
function getUserInfo(length) {
    var peoplepickerarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var keys = peoplepickerArray[i].GetAllUserKeys();
        getUserId(keys);
    }
}

function getUserId(loginName) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        userId = user.get_id();
        console.log(userId)
        PPuserIds.push(userId);
    }, function(sender, args) {
        console.log('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
    });
}
```

I should wait for the "executeQueryAsync", don't have any idea though. I don't understand the jQuery documentation of promise...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/akzfq7o4/1/ ?

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/akzfq7o4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern, yet nicely working example:

```
const getUserInfo = async () => {
    var peoplepickerarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

    const pickerPromises = peoplepickerarray.map(picker =>
        getUserId(picker.GetAllUserKeys())
    );

    const userIds = await Promise.all(pickerPromises);
    console.log(userIds);
};

const context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

const getUserId = async loginName =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(() => {
            resolve(user.get_id());
        }, reject);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with `async` functions inside a loop, there is a feature in SharePoint CSOM API called [Request Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx) that in my opinion better suits this scenario. The main advantage of this approach that the number of requests to the server could be minimized.

The below example demonstrates how to load multiple users by login names using a *single request* too the server:

```
function loadUsers(loginNames,success,error) {
       var result = [];
       var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       for(var i = 0; i < loginNames.length;i++){
          var user = ctx.get_web().ensureUser(loginNames[i]);
          ctx.load(user);
          result.push(user);   
       }
       ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function() {
                success(result); 
            }, 
            error);
}
```

Usage

```
loadUsers(['username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'],
   function(users){
       for(var i = 0; i < users.length;i++){
           console.log(users[i].get_id());
       }
   },
   function(sender, args) {
          console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
   });
```

Comment: ['username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'] is the user key, right?
Is it correct that I can get all my UIDs with that one function?

Comment: Somehow I can't get it working... it always gets executed on load. How can I properly call that function?

Comment: Hm, since the specified example works for me, could you share some details, what is being passed via keys variable?

Comment: Keys is a variable containing a userKey for the current [i] in the loop.